# Define required or not for array fields in the prisma datamodel

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

What are the differences of followings. when to use a one over the other?

```
zones: [Zone]
zones: [Zone!]
zones: [Zone]!
zones: [Zone!]!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be summarised with this table of allowed values based on the definition:

```
values         | [Zone] | [Zone!] | [Zone]! | [Zone!]! |
--------------------------------------------------------
null           |    ✔   |    ✔    |    X    |     X    |
[]             |    ✔   |    ✔    |    ✔    |     ✔    |
[null]         |    ✔   |    X    |    ✔    |     X    |
["a","b"]      |    ✔   |    ✔    |    ✔    |     ✔    |
["a",null,"c"] |    ✔   |    X    |    ✔    |     X    |
```

Most of the time, you will need to use `[Zone!]!` as it ensures that no null values will be found in your array.

Comment: Perfect!... also the answer is nicely organized.

Comment: what if I want to avoid [ ]? how is [ ] different from [null]? thanks

Comment: In a GraphQL shema, you cannot specify the required length, which means you cannot avoid an empty array ([]).

Comment: The difference between [] and [null] is that [] is an empty array, while [null] is an array with one element which is null. It's the same difference that can be seen in most languages.